# Remote Network Access Control

Tags: password, proxy, remote

I'd like to know which software/process would help me do the following:

I've got two offices (A & B) in which I will install Ubuntu 14.04 on their respective Desktop PCs.
Both offices would have separate internet access (via Ethernet/WiFi from a 'regular' modem).

I'd like to:
1. Set up the browser on Desktop B such that it needs a password to browse the internet.
2. Be able to set the Time Limit for each of those sessions.
3. At the end of that session time out, change the password needed for the next login (of course).

What software is needed and how do I go about setting it up?

I've thought of perhaps using Teamviewer and remotely controlling the desktop. So once I get an employee to fire up Teamviewer on B for me, then from Desktop A, I input the Browsing password. So no need of setting up Time-out sessions or changing passwords.
Does that sound doable? If so, then I just need advice on how to setup password to restrict access to, say, Firefox. Then, there would be no need of setting up Proxies (yay!)

Much thanks to all you geniuses.
P.S.:
-I'm absolutely new to Ubuntu....
-Desktops A & B are in very different locations....
-The employees are not knowledgeable enough to figure out a hack, so the process needn't necessarily be too complex

Answer (score 0):

The *Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS* came pre-installed with **Remmina** that use the **RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol**, then it connect with *Microsoft Windows* OS too.

It setup is full feature and tweaks.

Beyond it have **SFTP**, **SSH** and **VNC** as alternative protocols.

http://remmina.sourceforge.net/